# Table inheritance without new columns

Tags: postgresql, inheritance

Can PostgreSQL make a child table without any additional columns? I’m thinking of something like a `Developer` table that inherits from an `Employee` table. Then, when I insert into `Developer`, that record will be visible in both `Developer` and `Employee` tables. It would be a good way to get away from an `IsDeveloper` column.

Comment: That's how partitioning was implemented before Postgres 10. See the examples here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-IMPLEMENTATION-INHERITANCE

Comment: I didn’t know that. The tutorial videos I’ve been watching target 9.x. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may let the columns empty when you create the child table:

```
CREATE TABLE developer () INHERITS (employee);
```

So `developer` has no additional columns.

Comment: This is beautiful